# Lambda Calculus Xor

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, lambda-calculus

How do you prove $\mathsf{xor} \, \mathsf{True}\, \mathsf{True}$ is false in lambda calculus using call-by-value reduction.

This is the approach I tried but it is not working:

$$\mathsf{xor} \equiv \lambda xy.x(y F T) y$$

$$\mathsf{xor} \, T T \equiv (\lambda xy.x(y F T)y) T 
T$$

$$\mathsf{xor}\, T T \equiv (\lambda xy.x(y (\lambda x y.y) (\lambda x y.x))y) T 
T$$

Then by beta reduction of leftmost inner

$$\mathsf{xor}\, T T \equiv (\lambda xy.x(y (\lambda y.y) )y) T 
T$$

But I feel there is a mistake somewhere as the steps above did not lead me to the expected answer.

Comment: this question most likely belongs in the computer science theory forum, where you will most likely get more traction on it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken. The subterm $yFT$ does not contain any $\beta$-redex. Indeed, every term of the form $MNL$ must be read as $(MN)L$, and not as $M(NL)$ (technically, the application is said to be *left-associative*).
This means that $yFT = (yF)T = (y (\lambda xy.y))\lambda xy.x$ and so there is no $\beta$-redex to fire.

Therefore, in the term $\mathsf{xor}\, T T = (\lambda xy.x(y (\lambda x y.y) (\lambda x y.x))y) T T$ there is only one $\beta$-redex, made up of the subterm from the first occurrence of $\lambda x$ to the first occurrence of $T$.
You can easily see that the leftmost-innermost reduction from $\mathsf{xor}\, T T $ yields $F$, as expected.